# How do I migrate my Angular 4 product specifically to an Angular 7 program instead of the latest

Tags: angular, migration, angular7

I am trying to update a product from Angular 4 to a newer Angular 7.2. 
But I am not trying to update it to the newest Angular 8

How would I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/) tool, specify that you want to go from 4.0 to 7.2 as well as the other parameters and follow the steps.

Comment: I was looking at that, I was hoping somebody would suggest something more efficient but I suppose I can't avoid how tedious it's going to be.

Comment: I'd say this is super efficient, just remember to use `ng update @angular/core@7.2.15`.